# SignalR, SharePoint, Owin issue

Tags: asp.net, api, sharepoint, signalr

There is a scenario where we have two applications. One is share point and other obe is Web API.
For security point of view, we need to deploy second stand alone project into the firsy application.
In IIS, I deployed one application. In that folder I deployed another application and make it as web application.
Now everythings runs fine. SharePoint applicantion consume APIs correctly.
Now, I have include signalR to both application where web api application is server and share point is client.
I have global asax file and add startup file for owin signalR. If I add owin automatic startup to false then application runs fine but signalR will not work.
If I start owin then neither api work nor signalR will work.

Important point is when I run SharePoint application from IIS and run web api from visual studio and set path of web api for signalR then it works fine.

What could be the issue?